# No Reverse Match Why?

Tags: django

I get this error whenever i try to open my localhost:8000 which happens to be the homepage of the app i'm working on.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<slug>[\\-\\w]+)/$']
```

Below are the {% url %} use in template, my models.py, my urls.py and views.py

What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

```
#in Template.
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' %}" class="button tiny">View</a>

#my urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^categories/$', views.MyCategory.as_view(), name='all_categories'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.CategoryDetail.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
    url(r'^tip/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ToolkitDetail.as_view(), name='toolkit_detail'),
)

#my models.py
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=750)
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

#my views.py
class MyCategory(ListView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'category.html'

class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    slug_field = 'slug'
    model = Category
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
```

The above is the summation of my problem. Please any assistance is appreciated. I'm sure its clear enough my problem, but since StackOverflow won't let me post without adding more text, I'm doing so. I think the excerpt above is self explanatory as to my problem. I think I'm released to post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url name 'category_detail' has compulsory parameter - slug. So in template you could write:

```
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' category.slug %}" class="button tiny">View</a>
```

As your model have special method for generating url you can do it simple:

```
{{ category.get_absolute_url }}
```

Comment: You know what, Eugene, your first suggestion didn't work though. However the second approach was the Baaam!! for me. It worked! But it still leaves me wondering as I've used the {% url 'text' %} successfully in my previous project using version 1.5 of django. So why all of a sudden the url isn't working? Or its got something to do with the regex of the URL too?

Thanks for your help. I'm glad i can interlink my pages now.

Comment: As I wrote in answer you must pass compulsory parameter to url template tag, after url name. This parameter determined in your urls.py and view function. It's strange that earlier your code work as you said, django use get_absolute_url method in admin. In custom template you should call it by yourself as I wrote. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: Okay. Both working. I wasn't doing it right the first time with the first suggestion. I was calling a non-existing variable. I'm glad to know this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your template contains `{% url 'category_detail' %}`, i.e. tries to reverse "category_detail" url pattern, without giving the required `slug` keyword argument. This might work:

```
{% url 'category_detail' slug="foo" %}
```

Comment: So in the slug="foo" what do I put in the "foo" part since the urls is dynamically generated? Interesting answer.

Comment: category_detail is usually a detail view _of a specific category_, so you need to tell it what category do you want. You do that by supplying its slug.